Problema al instalar PyTorch 1.9.0 en Windows 10 x64 con Python 3.8 usando pip
Estoy intentando instalar PyTorch 1.9.0 en mi sistema Windows 10 de 64 bits con Python 3.8, pero pip no puede encontrar la distribución adecuada. Cuando intento instalarlo usando el comando:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

obtengo el siguiente error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Para resolver el problema, intenté descargar el archivo .whl correspondiente desde la página https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/ y elegí torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl. Sin embargo, al intentar instalarlo con el comando:
pip install torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

recibo el siguiente error:
ERROR: torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Detalles adicionales:

Sistema Operativo: Windows 10 x64
Versión de Python: 3.8

Actualizacion
Por desgracia despues de actualizar pip y también wheel y setuptool ya no puedo descargar torch.
Aqui esta la salida de python -m pip debug -v:
(webapp_env) PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\C\end2end_ng\webapp> python -m pip debug -v
WARNING: This command is only meant for debugging. Do not use this with automation for parsing and getting these details, since the output and options of this command may change without notice.
pip version: pip 24.2 from C:\Users\antoi\Documents\C\end2end_ng\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
sys.version: 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
sys.executable: C:\Users\antoi\Documents\C\end2end_ng\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
sys.getdefaultencoding: utf-8
sys.getfilesystemencoding: utf-8
locale.getpreferredencoding: cp1252
sys.platform: win32
sys.implementation:
  name: cpython
'cert' config value: Not specified
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: None
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: None
pip._vendor.certifi.where(): C:\Users\antoi\Documents\C\end2end_ng\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem
pip._vendor.DEBUNDLED: False
vendored library versions:
  CacheControl==0.14.0
  distlib==0.3.8
  distro==1.9.0
  msgpack==1.0.8
  packaging==24.1
  platformdirs==4.2.2
  pyproject-hooks==1.0.0
  requests==2.32.3
  certifi==2024.07.04
  idna==3.7
  urllib3==1.26.18
  rich==13.7.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  pygments==2.18.0
  typing_extensions==4.12.2 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  resolvelib==1.0.1
  setuptools==70.3.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  tomli==2.0.1
  truststore==0.9.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
Compatible tags: 30
  cp38-cp38-win32
  cp38-abi3-win32
  cp38-none-win32
  cp37-abi3-win32
  cp36-abi3-win32
  cp35-abi3-win32
  cp34-abi3-win32
  cp33-abi3-win32
  cp32-abi3-win32
  py38-none-win32
  py3-none-win32
  py37-none-win32
  py36-none-win32
  py35-none-win32
  py34-none-win32
  py33-none-win32
  py32-none-win32
  py31-none-win32
  py30-none-win32
  cp38-none-any
  py38-none-any
  py3-none-any
  py37-none-any
  py36-none-any
  py35-none-any
  py34-none-any
  py33-none-any
  py32-none-any
  py31-none-any
  py30-none-any


Python va en la 3.12. ¿No sería mejor actualizar Python primero?

Si no tienes pip actualizado, actualizalo y de paso también wheel y setuptools: python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools y prueba de nuevo. Si no funciona, agrega la salida de python -m pip debug -v a ver si da alguna pista.

Tu pregunta esta respondida aquí  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239310/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-0-0 con respecto a las versiones de pytorch. Tu versión es incompatible, lo mejor seria que crees un entorno virtual con la versión de python que si lo soporte.

Gracias por tu comentario @Synay . Sin embargo, según lo que investigué, la versión de PyTorch que estoy tratando de instalar (torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl) debería ser compatible con Python 3.8 en Windows x64. ¿Podrías aclarar por qué crees que esta versión no es compatible? Tal vez me esté perdiendo algún detalle específico. También, si hay una configuración más adecuada, me gustaría saber cuál sería. ¡Gracias de antemano por tu ayuda!

El problema es que estás usando la versión de 32 bits de Python, la salida de pip debug lo muestra claramente en varios puntos, por ejemplo:

sys.version: [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] (compilador de C usado para compilar Python).
sys.platform: win32
Tags de compatibilad: no aparece win64 por ningun lado, en cambio tenemos: cp38-cp38-win32

Tu sistema operativo es de 64 bits, el paquete que has descargado es para CPython 3.8 de 64 bits (versión para CPU, no CUDA), pero el intérprete Python es de 32 bits y PyTorch nunca fue compatible con sistemas de 32 bits que yo recuerde.

Si necesitas usar PyTorch 1.9 tus únicas opciones son Python 3.8 y Python 3.9, ambos de 64 bits (amd64)

Si necesitas específicamente Python 3.8 para tu proyecto no deberias tener problemas ya que es la mínima versión soportada por PyTorch, pero tendrás que instalar la versión de 64 bits del intérprete.
La última versión de la rama 3.8 en la que se provee instalador oficial es Python 3.8.10:

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/python-3.8.10-amd64.exe

La última versión es la 3.8.18, pero a partir de 3.8.10 son solo actualizaciones de seguridad y no se proporcionan binarios, tendrias que compilarlo.

En caso contrario te aconsejaría actualizar tanto Python como PyTorch, en concreto Python 3.8 estará en EOL dentro de un par de meses (finales de Octubre 2024).



Muchas gracias FJ, estas respuestas siguen siendo tan claras como antes, realmente eres el mejor de nosotros.
